# DataMember Attribute is not honored in dotnet core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I created a sample dotnet core 3.0 Web API project and did the following changes,

1. Create a Model class TestData

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
namespace WebApplication17.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class TestData
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "testaction")]
        public string Action { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I made changes in controller `WeatherForecastController`, to add a post endpoint

```
[HttpPost("package/{packageName}/version/{version}")]
public void Post(string packageName, string version, [FromBody] TestData activityPayload)
{
    Console.WriteLine(activityPayload.Action);
}
```

Now I made a call from postman or curl with body

```
{   
    "testaction": "action"  
}
```

Still in `Post` method of `WeatherForecastController`, `activityPayload.Action` is *null*.

I was expecting it to be 'action'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Asp.Net Core 3 does not support `[DataContract]`, `[DataMember]` by default and it does not look like they would be adding it any time soon based on [this Github Issue: `System.Text.Json support to System.Runtime.Serialization`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38758)

If you’d like to switch back to the previous default of using `Newtonsoft.Json`, which does honor those attributes, then you'll have to do the following:

1. Install the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson) NuGet package.
2. In `ConfigureServices()` add a call to `AddNewtonsoftJson()`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    //...

    services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(); //<--

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 18):

As of .NET Core 3.0 RC1 the `System.Text.Json` library does not have support for `System.Runtime.Serialization` attributes. You can find an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38758) which is tracking this omission but right now it does not appear that there is any intention to change that.

## Option 1: Newtonsoft.Json

What you can do in the interim is switch to using `Newtonsoft.Json` as the JSON serializer for ASP.NET Core 3.0 which should restore this functionality (at the cost of not leveraging the `System.Text.Json` parser which is a fair bit faster).

First, add a reference to the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson) package in your project:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And then call the extension on your services collection.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson();
}
```

## Option 2: Use System.Text.Json.Serialization

On the other hand, if you're happy to define your models without `System.Runtime.Serialization` attributes and use the `System.Text.Json.Serialization` attributes instead, then you can do the following:

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
namespace WebApplication17.Models
{
    public class TestData
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("testaction")]
        public string Action { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can find the full list of supported attributes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.0

Answer (score 9):

Add `[JsonPropertyName("testaction")]` attribute to the `Action` property. This should solve your problem.

See here for more:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/

Answer (score 0):

My two cents.

The following example should help.

The following is the json that I get as response from an OData Api.

```js
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost/odata/$metadata#GadgetsOdata(Id,ProductName,Cost,Brand,Type)",
    "@odata.count": 3,
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "ProductName": "Pen Drive",
            "Brand": "Sony",
            "Cost": 600,
            "Type": "Accessories"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "ProductName": "Head Phone",
            "Brand": "Sony",
            "Cost": 3000,
            "Type": "Computer Accessories"
        },
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "ProductName": "Key board",
            "Brand": "Hp",
            "Cost": 1000,
            "Type": "Computer Accessories"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following are the classes I used to deserialize.

```cs
public class ExpectedODataGadgetModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("@odata.count")]
    public int ODataCount { get; set; } = default!;
    [JsonPropertyName("@odata.context")]
    public string ODataContext { get; set; } = default!;

    public List<ExpectedGadgetModel> value { get; set; } = default!;
}
public class ExpectedGadgetModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Brand { get; set; } = default!;
    public decimal Cost { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Type { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Note the `JsonPropertyName` attribute.

Finally this is how I desterilize it.

```cs
var responseStream = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
var gadgets = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ExpectedODataGadgetModel>(responseStream);
```

Here _httpClient is `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` object that we use in .net core.

And `JsonSerializer` comes from `System.Text.Json` and not NewtonsoftJson.