# In my POST request action JsonProperty mapping is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a model and controller like the following

```
public class OrderModel
{
    [JsonProperty("order_id")]        
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("delivery_shift")]
    public string DeliveryShift { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceType { get; set; }
}
```

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class OrderController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index([FromBody] OrderModel order) {

        return new JsonResult(new
        {
            order.ID,
            order.DeliveryShift,
            order.InvoiceType
        });
    }
}
```

Now when i submit a post request with this json in the body then `order_id` and `delivery_shift` doesn't map with the model.

```
{"order_id": "OrderID", "delivery_shift": "evening", "InvoiceType": "DUE"}
```

but it works when i submit the json in this format, **BUT I need the previous format to work**.

```
{"ID": "OrderID", "DeliveryShift": "evening", "InvoiceType": "DUE"}
```

Thanks.

**SOLVED**

Thanks to @AhmetUrun Updating model with `JsonPropertyName` attribute worked.

```
public class OrderModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("order_id")]        
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("delivery_shift")]
    public string DeliveryShift { get; set; }

    public string InvoiceType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: seems like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492821/webapi-deserializing-and-serializing-alternate-property-names.
so addindg this attribute should work `[DataMember(Name = "field_name")]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebApi - Deserializing and serializing alternate property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492821/webapi-deserializing-and-serializing-alternate-property-names)

Comment: that solution didn't work!

Comment: what is the content-type?So when you post the request check the received request's content type.It should be application/json then only it will work.

Comment: can you share the model after you've added DataMember attribute as I've told. you need add DataContract atrribute on top of your model class as well.

Comment: i'm submitting a json using insomnia

Comment: Yes i tried adding DataContract it didn't work 

```C#
    [DataContract]
    public class OrderModel
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "order_id")]        
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "delivery_shift")]
        public string DeliveryShift { get; set; }

        public string InvoiceType { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: BTW I'm using asp.net core 3.1

Comment: DataMember is very speciifc for WCF but for webapi JSONProperty should work.Anyway JSONProperty  as precedence over DataMember

Comment: @HameedSyed no it's not specific to wcf, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization
@MahabubulHasan you need to configure web api to use DataContract Json Serializer if you haven't done already
`var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;`

Comment: Do i need to add anything in my `StartUp.cs` file after `services.AddControllersWithViews();` this line?

Comment: @AhmetUrun where do i put that line?

Comment: check this question to understand usage of serializes in web api https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371040/am-i-using-datacontractjsonserializer-or-the-json-net-one-in-my-web-api-2

Comment: @AhmetUrun  that solution is not for asp.net core but asp.net https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization

Comment: try this `[JsonPropertyName("property_name")]`

Comment: [tag:asp.net-core-3.0] and later use a completely different JSON serializer by default.  `JsonPropertyName` works with that new serializer.  See: [DataMember Attribute is not honored in dotnet core 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57965350/3744182), [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55666826/3744182) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58299628/3744182).